# Umbraco Packages

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-blog

I am trying to install umbraco packages such as Articulate (used for blogging) but every time I try and install a package I get redirected back to the package page. I have tried to install a local package but it still redirects back to packages.

I am running Windows 10 and VS 2015. I have tried Umbrco 7.5 and Umbraco 7.7 version.

Is there away to detect what the issue is in my umbraco installation if it not a known issue?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console (dev tools)?

Comment: I can not see any errors just GET request when I try and install the package  "XHR finished loading: GET" .

Comment: Have you tried using Nuget to install the package?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help I have added the answer to how I managed to add a package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that I can install the packages on another computer. I believe it to be the network I am on at work is the course of the issue. I worked on a computer that had more privileges and it worked. It might have been because  not be able to write to a particular location.

I know in IIS I have to give security permissions to user IIS_IUSERS in the website folder. In order to get the website working.